# Does `-fsanitize=bounds-strict` check anything that `-fsanitize=address` does not?

Tags: c, gcc, address-sanitizer, memory-safety

The GCC manual says:

> -fsanitize=bounds-strict
>
> This option enables strict instrumentation of array bounds.  Most out
> of bounds accesses are detected, including flexible array members and
> flexible array member-like arrays.  Initializers of variables with
> static storage are not instrumented.

However, here, `sum` can access its argument out-of-bounds, despite the use of `-fsanitize=address,undefined,bounds-strict` (when `offset` is chosen to reach into the wrong array):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define n 1000

typedef double array[n];

double sum(array a, long offset)
{
    double acc = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        acc += a[i + offset];

    return acc;
}

int main()
{
    array a;
    array b;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) b[i] = 2;

    long offset = b - a;
    printf("%ld\n", offset);

    printf("%f\n", sum(a, offset));
}
```

Compiling this with GCC 10.2 gives me:

```
$ gcc -pedantic -Wall -std=c17 -fsanitize=address,undefined,bounds-strict memory_errors_two_arrays.c && ./a.out 
1032
2000.000000
```

So the code dereferenced a `double[1000]` with 2031 and didn't even blink.

Does `-fsanitize=bounds-strict` check anything that `-fsanitize=address` does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does -fsanitize=bounds-strict check anything that -fsanitize=address does not?

Yes.

`-fsanitize=bounds-strict` is about checking *array* bounds, not the bounds of general objects.  It uses compile-time information about array lengths, **drawn largely from the types of the lvalues used for access**, to generate instrumentation.  That is orthogonal to the allocation size of dynamically-allocated objects, and the kind of information used is unavailable from many of the common idioms for creating and accessing dynamically allocated objects, such as the one in the original version of this question.

Consider this, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int a[2][256] = {0};

    printf("%d\n", a[0][256]);
}
```

If I compile with `-fsanitze=address` and run the result, it just prints "0".

If I compile with `-fsanitize=bounds-strict` and run it, I get this report:

```
santest.c:7:24: runtime error: index 256 out of bounds for type 'int [256]'
```

(and it also prints "0").

Apparently, it is also notable that although the diagnostic information emitted by `-fsanitize` instrumentation is styled as error messages, these do not represent *fatal* errors.  The objective is for such informational messages to be in addition to the normal behavior of the program, not to replace or subvert the normal behavior.  In particular, `-fsanitize` does not abort the program when an incorrect memory access is detected, though some other mechanism might cause such a failure in some cases.

---

After the original version of this answer was posted, the question was modified to present a different situation.  With respect to the version that is current as I write this, it is relevant that it is relatively easy to *hide* or *moot* the type information on which `-fsanitize`'s `bounds-strict` mode relies.  The example code currently presented in the question does this by interposing a function call interface between a declared array and the array access.

In this context, I observe that in the scope of

> ```
> #define n 1000
>
> typedef double array[n];
> ```

, this function declaration ...

> ```
> double sum(array a, long offset)
> ```

is 100% equivalent to

```
double sum(double *a, long offset)
```

.  The `typedef` notwithstanding, it does not convey any information about how many more elements follow `*a` in the array, if any, of which it is a member.  This function must in fact accept pointers into arrays of arbitrary length, so not only is there is no information for `bounds-strict` to use for generating instrumentation, it would be incorrect for it to be instrumented to assume a particular array length.

Contrast with this variation:

```
double access_flat(double *p, int i) {
    return p[i];
}

double access_dim200(double (*p)[200], int i) {
    return (*p)[i];
}

double access_dim100(double (*p)[100], int i) {
    return (*p)[i];
}
 
int main(void) {
    double *p = calloc(200, sizeof *p);
    double q[2][100] = {0};

    printf("p, flat:   %lf\n", access_flat(p, 100));
    printf("p, dim100: %lf\n", access_dim100((double (*)[100]) p, 100));
    printf("p, dim200: %lf\n\n", access_dim200((double (*)[200]) p, 100));

    printf("q, flat:   %lf\n", access_flat((double *) q, 100));
    printf("q, dim100: %lf\n", access_dim100(q, 100));
    printf("q, dim200: %lf\n", access_dim200((double (*)[200]) q, 100));
}
```

When compiled with `-fsanitize=bounds-strict`, the output of this program is:

```
p, flat:   0.000000
santest.c:14:16: runtime error: index 100 out of bounds for type 'double [100]'
p, dim100: 0.000000
p, dim200: 0.000000

q, flat:   0.000000
q, dim100: 0.000000
q, dim200: 0.000000
```

This shows several things, among them that

- `bounds-strict` is indeed using the type of the lvalue used for access to generate instrumentation, and
- the version of `-fsanitize` in my GCC (v8.5.0) treats automatically allocated (and statically allocated; not shown) arrays differently than dynamically allocated ones, and
- the version of `-fsanitize=bounds-strict` in my GCC is buggy for automatically allocated (and statically allocated; not shown) arrays, failing to report some array-bounds overruns.

Bugs notwithstanding, again yes, `bounds-check` mode does check some things that `address` mode does not.  For me, `bounds-check` also requires an additional library, `libubsan`, that `address` mode by itself does not.  The two modes have overlapping area of application, but their design is different, and each detects some issues that the other does not.

Comment: strange that it doesn't exit

Comment: Who says it doesn't exit, @MWB?  I didn't think it was necessary to specifically say so, but yes, either way it is compiled, the program exits.  For me, anyway.

Comment: It doesn't exit right after the error - "prints 0".

Comment: I strengthened the example in the question dereferencing an array `double[1000]` out-of-bounds. It appears that `bounds-strict` works only in some very narrow circumstances.

Comment: I'm not much of a language lawyer, but I think `double[100]` is still a C array, even if it's dynamically allocated. The man page doesn't say that the arrays must be stack-allocated.

Comment: @MWB, the question was whether `-fsanitize=bounds-strict` checks anything that `-fsanitze=address` does not.  The answer is demonstrably "yes", as I show.  In fact, they are orthogonal. Also, I discuss how the former uses compile time information to create instrumentation, so yes, if you hide your array's actual type by passing instead a pointer, as you do in your example by calling the `sum()` function, the compiler has nothing with which to produce instrumentation for `bounds-strict`.  And make no mistake: that's indeed what your example does, the `array` typedef notwithstanding.

Comment: The first argument of `sum` is of type `double[1000]`, which is an array of length known at compile time. The compiler could have inserted a check before `a[i+offset]` to make sure `i+offset` is less than `1000`. The man page is highly suggestive that it should have.

Comment: I agree that you found a case where `bounds-strict` does something, but *"..., which is not available for dynamically-allocated objects"* seems incorrect.

Comment: It looks like even for stack-allocated arrays, out-of-bounds access is not detected -- I removed `malloc` from the example. I hope you agree that your current answer is not quite correct.

Comment: @MWB, I have updated this answer to make it more precise and to address some of the new issues that you introduced in your modifications to the question.